# FeathersJS Mongoose model for one-row data

Tags: mongoose, feathersjs

I need to write a Feathers service for non-repeatable data.
E.g. `Settings` model must contain attributes like `title`, `description`, `nightMode`, etc.

I see two possible approaches.

1. Horizontal:

```
new Schema({
    title: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    nightMode: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  });
```

2. Vertical:

```
new Schema({
    key: { type: String, required: true },
    value: { type: String }
  });
```

The vertical approach has the drawback of needing to seed model with correct aliases and the fact that `value` can be only String. But horizontal seems too much if there will be many (100+) attributes.
Also, I'd like to be able to batch update these attributes with one API call.

I'm sure this problem has been solved before me, but can't google any good example. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please? Any tips for writing Feathers service for such a model?

Comment: This is really an opinion question, but I've generally done the horizontal approach -- I like the atomicity of a single row/document holding the settings, and it's easier to code in validations and type checking for discrete fields.  Generic key/value tables/collections are usually a code smell to me.

Comment: I would choose the horizontal approach too because I can well define the wanted settings structure. Also I am curious about how you setup this single row service system. May you put some code sample of the service (class, hooks etc...)? Thanks!

Comment: @Soullivaneuh I chose the horizontal approach too, but its implementation in Feathers appeared to be too hacky. In the end, I switched that particular project to NestJS. It needs more boilerplate but is more flexible.